# How to convert to lowercase all columns except a few specific ones?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to convert to lowercase all columns within a dataframe except two. To convert all the dataframe I usually do

```
df=df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
```

My dataset is

```
Time    Name       Surname       Age  Notes        Comments
 12     Mirabel    Gutierrez     23   None        Already Paid
 09     Kim        Stuart        45   In debt     Should refund 100 EUR
```

and so on.

I would like to transform into lowercase all the columns except `Notes` and `Comments`.

```
Time    Name       Surname       Age  Notes        Comments
 12     mirabel    gutierrez     23   None        Already Paid
 09     kim        stuart        45   In debt     Should refund 100 EUR
```

What can I try?

Comment: ``df.iloc[:, :-2] = df.iloc[:, :-2].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())`` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably simply want to create a list of the relevant columns:

`lowerify_cols = [col for col in df if col not in ['Notes','Comments']]`

Then you can use your code snippet:

`df[lowerify_cols]= df[lowerify_cols].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower(),axis=1)`